# Change multiple file's content

Tags: sed, fedora, find, command, xargs

I have a file called list.txt and its content is as follows:

```
paswd.c
acnt.c
control.c
...
```

(The rest is omitted)

I want to do something like the pseudo code:

```
point to first line of list.txt;
while (list.txt not reaching end of file)
{
    get string from line;
    find -name 'string';
    if (find)
    {
        delete first 7 lines in file;
    }
    advance one line;
}
```

I believe the combination of **find**, **xargs** and **sed** can achieve this.

Comment: what if a file found that it was containing less or equal to 7 lines?

Comment: @αғsнιη I tested sed to delete first 7 lines in a file that containing less than 7 lines. The outcome is that it become empty file. That's what I want it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like

```
$ xargs -a list.txt -I myfilename find . -name myfilename -exec sed 1,7d '{}' \;
```

- xargs reads the name of the files in list.txt and replaces the `myfilename` pattern with the name of the file read in the find command
- find will find your file and pass it to sed wich delete the first 7 lines (or empty the file if there is less than 7 lines)